# dateutil parser: how to parse time separated with blank spaces?

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

I need to turn string that comes to me in the following format ' 7/ 7/2001 16 14 58' into a datetime object, but white spaces are not recognized as a time delimiter. I believe parser only recognizes [-,:/]. How can I add white spaces to dateutil?

The following code:

```
    from dateutil import parser
    example_datetime = ' 7/ 7/2001 16 14 58'
    parsed_datetime = parser.parse(example_datetime)

    print(parsed_datetime)
```

Returns this error:

```
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', ' 7/ 7/2001 16 14 58')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you do not use the `datetime` library of `python` and specify your format?

```
from datetime import datetime
parsed_datetime = datetime.strptime(example_datetime, '%d/ %m/%Y %H %M %S')
print(parsed_datetime)

out:
datetime.datetime(2001, 7, 7, 16, 14, 58)
```

Comment: I should have clarified...The data that comes to me CAN be in that format, but not necessarily in a specific format. I am using dateutil to make sense of many different time-stamp data formats.

Comment: If you need to handle variable whitespace, you could do something like this to normalize first: `re.sub('\s+', ' ', re.sub('\\s*/\\s*', '/', ' 7/ 7/2001 16 14 58'.strip()))`

Comment: @ChristianAbbott You should probably edit your question to clarify what formats you want to handle.

Comment: hmmmm, the only think comes to mind is if you use `try` and `except` and do the above for all your possible formats